# Как задать появление BottomSheetBehabior по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

Делаю таким образом, но не появляется

```
@OnClick(R.id.btnMap)
public void click(){
    initBottomSheet();
    Log.d("TAG", "!!!");
}
private void initBottomSheet() {
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(layout_bottom);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(340);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
    initBottomSheetStateListener(bottomSheetBehavior);
}


private void initBottomSheetStateListener(@NonNull BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior) {
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    });
}
```

И разметка

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="220dp"
android:background="@drawable/shape_bottom_sheet"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно, пока не задал вопрос не решил проблему, но оказалось просто

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(layout_bottom);
}

private void initBottomSheet() {
    bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    initBottomSheetStateListener(bottomSheetBehavior);
}

private void initBottomSheetStateListener(@NonNull BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior) {
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    });
}
```